# How to plot a “pivot table” with 3 variables, using the number of observations as the size of the point?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pivot-table

I've been trying to get this through a couple of routes, but no luck.

I have two columns, "Type" (strings) and "Units" (integers). I want the x-axis to be Type, the Y-axis to be the **sum** of the Units per Type, and the size of the points based on the number of observations for each Type (gapminder style).

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. plot(xtabs(Type ~ Units)): This gets the right x/y relationship, but I don't see how to include the shape/size to be represented by the number of observations
2. ggplot(data, aes(Type, Units)) + geom_count(): Half a step back, since I've lost the sum, but at least now I have an idea of which Type has more observations.

In a way, I want a static gapminder plot.

Ideally, I would like to do it with ggplot2 (or anything but the default), since the graphs are nicer; but I'll take any pointers.

I feel quite close, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Update:

```
structure(list(CONTRIBUTOR_NAME = c("DATA LTD", 
"GEORGE", "PHIL", "JOHN J LOVE", 
"E LOVE", "MADISON LTD", "NAOMI", 
" HARRISON", " GILL", "RON R ", "MARIBETH ", 
"BEV", "P ANN", "DYCK", "GEHRING", 
"HARVIE ", "SUSAN", "JANE", "RANDY C", 
"GEORGE N "), DATE = structure(c(13511, 15826, 14461, 
16491, 12874, 15295, 15881, 13466, 14373, 16560, 15223, 13518, 
14096, 16555, 15861, 15644, 15923, 13153, 15741, 15091), class = "Date"), 
    AMOUNT = c(500, 200, 12.5, 30, 300, 332, 10, 10, 100, 23, 
    20, 22, 25, 10, 25, 50, 10, 40, 35, 150), CLASS = c("Corporations", 
    "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", 
    "Corporations", "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", 
    "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", 
    "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", 
    "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals"), PARTY = c("PARTY 5", 
    "PARTY 1", "PARTY 1", "PARTY 1", "PARTY 1", "PARTY 5", 
    "PARTY 1", "PARTY 5", "PARTY 5", "PARTY 1", 
    "PARTY 1", "PARTY 1", "PARTY 1", "PARTY 5", "PARTY 1", 
    "PARTY 5", "PARTY 1", "PARTY 1", "PARTY 1", "PARTY 1"
    ), BUSINESS = c("Businesses", "Individuals", "Individuals", 
    "Individuals", "Individuals", "Businesses", "Individuals", 
    "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", 
    "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", 
    "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", "Individuals", 
    "Individuals")), .Names = c("CONTRIBUTOR_NAME", "DATE", "AMOUNT", 
"CLASS", "PARTY", "BUSINESS"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide your data, so I can't illustrate with that.  I will use the built-in mtcars data instead.  You can get the number of observation of each type using `table` and then adjust the point size using the `cex` parameter.

```
plot(unique(mtcars$cyl), as.vector(xtabs(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars)), 
    xlim=c(3.5,8.5), ylim=c(130,310), pch=20,
    xlab="Cylinders", ylab="Sum of MPG", 
    cex = table(mtcars$cyl), col="#0000FF44")
```

[image: Gapminder style]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, this is not working for me, possibly because I have categorical variables in my x-axis? When I do the plot command I mention in my post, it works (though I don't get circles, only thin bars) but once I introduce as.vector, I lose the categories.

When I try the command as is, I am required to include an x-lim (which I can't provide)

Comment: Well, I should clarify: by "it works," I mean I get an output, though not exactly the desired one.

Comment: If you want us to help using your data, you must provide your data.   Try using `dput` on your data and paste it into the question.

Comment: I added dput(tails), since data is quite large. Does that help?

Comment: Not quite yet.  In your sample, almost all variables are constant. Instead,  try `dput(donations[sample(nrow(donations), 20), ])`  Also I assume that you want to sum the AMOUNTs.  Which variable do you want to aggregate by?

Comment: Heya, had to step out, didn't see your message until now. Data updated, I want to Aggregate Amount by Business as the y-axis, and the point size as the Count by Business. Thanks so much for your help—much appreciated!